# Mouse Enter & Mouse Leave on a form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form with child controls.
I want when user move mouse over the form, the form will be closed.
So I catch mouse enter and move leave on the form. But if I move mouse on any controls in form, mouse leave event will be also caught.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
When the cursor's position is on the form's caption region (this region is called non-client region). I move mouse out of this region, I can't receive the WM_MOUSELEAVE message as well as WM_NCMOUSELEAVE. Please help me in this problem. I want to receive a message when move mouse out of this region. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect when the mouse leaves the form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279472/how-to-detect-when-the-mouse-leaves-the-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you want to check if the cursor is in the scope of the control. Here is the solution:

(1) Add a `Panel` in the form which is the same size as your `Form`, and move all controls in the form to the panel. It's easy to change: open `MyForm.designer.cs`, add the panel, and change all statements like `this.Controls.Add(myLabel);` to `this.myPanel.Controls.Add(myLabel);`.

(2) Deal with `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events of the panel you added.

```
myPanel.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
{
    //enter
};

myPanel.MouseLeave += (sender, e) =>
{
   if (Cursor.Position.X < myPanel.Location.X 
       || Cursor.Position.Y < myPanel.Location.Y
       || Cursor.Position.X > myPanel.Location.X + myPanel.Width 
       || Cursor.Position.Y > myPanel.Location.Y + myPanel.Height)
   {
       //out of scope
   }
};
```

(3) Why not use `Form` in step 2? Why do we need a `Panel` with the same size? Try it yourself. The narrow border of the form will make you crazy.

(4) You can make the `if` statements in step 2 to an extension method, which is helpful to furthur usage.

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because you have gap between your child Controls on leaving from controls the form_mouseEnter event fires automatically

a way you can do like placing controls with no gap

or

If you don't want user to leave your Control you can set **boundary of cursor**
use this

```
Cursor.Clip=Control_name.Bounds;
```