# Make scrollbar(on user control) visible when cursor is inside user control

Tags: c#, winforms

Using C#.NET 4.5

- I'm attempting to `change` the **vScrollbar property** of the *User Control* **On** when **Entering**  and **Off** when **Leaving** the Control.
- I used `Mouse_Enter` and `Mouse_Leave`, **however** when leaving *across* another `control or the scroll bar` ( that did show ), the scroll bar disappeared.

Question:
**How do i check if the mouse is inside the user control field?**

Question 2: **How do i disable the scrollbar at the bottom of the user control? (Horisontal Scrollbar)**

> If you need more information or if i am unclear somewhere, then just tell me.
>   Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** This is the code for the user control:

```
public partial class EnemyStats : UserControl
{
    public EnemyStats()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Left = (this.Width / 2) - (label1.Width / 2);
        hpBar1.Width = this.Width - 8;


        // Here i add the event that shows the scrollbar to all controls;
        foreach (Control con in this.Controls)
        {
            con.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(EnemyStats_MouseEnter);
        }
    }

    public double enemyMaxHP
    {
        get
        {
            return hpBar1.maxValue;
        }
        set
        {
            hpBar1.maxValue = value;
        }
    }

    public double enemyHP
    {
        get
        {
            return hpBar1.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            hpBar1.Value = value;
        }
    }

    private void EnemyStats_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Width < label1.Width) this.Width = label1.Width;

        label1.Left = (this.Width / 2) - (label1.Width / 2);

        hpBar1.Width = this.Width - 8;
    }

    private void EnemyStats_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This scrollbar was added by dragging it from the toolbox onto the user control in the designer
        vScrollbar1.Visible = true;
    }

    private void EnemyStats_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This scrollbar was added by dragging it from the toolbox onto the user control in the designer
        vScrollbar1.Visible = false;
    }

}
```

But scrollbars does not work:

```
public void randomMethodInUserControl()
{
    this.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could do something with the GotFocus handler?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx

It basically handles when a user control is in use by user. I.E textbox is highlighted.

Comment: the problem is hiding the scrollbars is not easy when `AutoScroll` set to `true`

Comment: i am not using auto scroll

Comment: @MasterXD if so, how do you show the scrollbars? Or you add some `custom dedicated scrollbars` for your `usercontrol`?

Comment: You may want to consider handling the mouse enter/leave of the child controls: http://stackoverflow.com/a/279741/88217  specifically, the CheckMouseLeave method

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've found ( Assuming you are using a Textbox )

- with Textbox1 set to multi line ( and no scrollbars from the designer view and prepoulated with text ( long enough to use the Scrollbars ))

  ```
  private void textBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
  }

  private void textBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
  }
  ```
- How ever i did find that though this worked, when i wen't over the `Scrollbar Side, it stayed on` ( Similar to your going over other controls ). There for my solution to you ( though this is kind of a workaround ) would be to grab yourself a ( background color : Transparent ) `label` and **encase your textbox** with it. ( let it show in the designer to have a margin of 2-5px around your Textbox and let the textbox handle Mouse Enter and Mouse Leave events.

  ```
  private void label1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
  }

  private void label1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
  }
  ```

Comment: this.ScrollBars does not work or exist on my user control. How do i enable that?

Comment: Try and show me some of your code... that would be easier then me guessing what / where your at. thanks

Comment: could you also let me know what control you are using I'm still working off the assumption that its a `text box` control.

Comment: 1. Its a user control. this = The user control itself (the form if i could say so).                                                     2. I think i found a solution myself. I am just putting the usercontrol inside a panel with autoscroll on. The panel is a bit wider than the user control so that the scrollbar at the bottom of the pannel wont appear, due to reduced space cause of the vertical scrollbar. There are no lines around a panel so that wouldnt bother me. Anyways if you have a better solution, i would like to hear it.

Comment: No, Panels are the way to go. Just place all your Controls within the Panel Control of the Form. You should then be able to use the above logic to get your scroll bars working right. Glad to hear you got something